# Why my Tableview is reusing some cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a Todo list, i have a label and a button in the same cell, when i click the button, change the image button for that cell, but when i scrolled the table view the same button appears on the others cells, it was not to appear in cells that the button were not pressed.

Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath code

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! TaskTableViewCell


    cell.label.text = "Task Number: \(indexPath.row + 1)"
    cell.btnFavorite.setImage(UIImage(named: "star"), forState: .Normal)
    cell.btnFavorite.setImage(UIImage(named: "star-filled"), forState: .Selected)
    cell.btnFavorite.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ListOfTasksViewController.addRemoveFavoriteList), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)


    return cell
}

func addRemoveFavoriteList(sender : UIButton) {
    sender.selected = !sender.selected

}
```

Custom TableViewCell Class:

```
 import UIKit

class TaskTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnFavorite: FavoriteButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        label.text = nil
        btnFavorite.selected = false

    }

}
```

View Controller:

```
import UIKit

class ListOfTasksViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! TaskTableViewCell


        cell.label.text = "Task Number: \(indexPath.row + 1)"

        cell.btnFavorite.indexPath = indexPath.row

        cell.btnFavorite.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ListOfTasksViewController.addRemoveFavoriteList), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)


        return cell
    }

    func addRemoveFavoriteList(sender : FavoriteButton) {

        if sender.selected {
            sender.selected = false


        } else {
            sender.selected = true

            let index = NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.indexPath, inSection: 0)
            let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(index) as! TaskTableViewCell


        }

    }




}
```

Comment: It's not a "problem". Reuse is correct and desirable behavior. And you bought into it when you said `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, after all; what did you _think_ you were saying?

Comment: You need to update your datasource when you press the button on the cell.

Answer (score 2):

The cells in your table view are reused so as you scroll down, the cells going off screen are being put at the start of the queue before going back onto the screen at a different indexPath. This can cause some issues so you need to override the `prepareForReuse` method in your custom cell class.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {

    super.prepareForReuse()

    label.text = nil
    btnFavorite.selected = false
}
```

Comment: I did this, but when i press the button and i scroll down the button changed doesnt appear in other cells, (until there its OK) but when i scroll up again the button pressed is not with the same image, do you know why ?

Comment: Yes, because that cell went off the screen so it's prepared for reuse, you need to make sure your dataSource reflects any changes made via the cells. So when you press the button, you must update a value reflecting the button status of the corresponding object in your dataSource array.

Comment: Then when the cell comes back onto the screen, in your cellForRowAtIndexPath, you need to set the `selected` property of the button from the value of your object that reflects the button status.

Comment: Show me your dataSource and model if any

Comment: i just created my specific button: FavoriteButton : UIButton { var isFavorite : Bool? } but i dont code a specific thing to solve this problem, do you have any suggestion how can i implement the correct datasource?

Comment: Where are you getting the number of tasks for the number of rows in a section?

Comment: i will edit my post with my classes, will be better for you help me with this

Answer (score 0):

you need to add condition in the cellforaRowAtIndexPath.

you need to add flag in Array which track your selection.
then its check in cellforRowAtIndexPath.

for example

```
button.selected= No

if arrselectedIndexpath containObject:indexPath{
button.selected =yes
}
```